# Laravel: Eloquent OR Query Builder Orderby BINARY

Tags: laravel, binary, sql-order-by

I have a query string:

```
SELECT xxx FROM yyy ORDER BY BINARY name
```

How can I write that in Eloquent or Query Builder? Please help me.

Comment: $yourQuery->orderByRaw('here');

Comment: thank @HilmiErdemKEREN

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same scenario, but instead of using `orderByRaw` or `raw` method, I have to keep using the `orderBy` to maintain the Query Builder's `orders` array keys because I need the `direction` in there.

So this is what I did:
`->orderBy(DB::raw('BINARY foo'), 'DESC');`

So that way, it will still maintain Query Builder's `orders` property array keys
`column` and `direction`.